# Mixer installed on system are different on Safari and Firefox using java AudioSystem APIs

Tags: java, safari, javasound

Why does AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() returns different mixer information with respect to browsers?

Some mixers and DataLines are missing in Safari browser but are present in Firefox.

On Safari

```
2014-08-01 13:56:36:098 There are 3 mixer info objects
2014-08-01 13:56:36:099 Mixer Name:Default Audio Device
2014-08-01 13:56:36:100 Mixer Name:Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:56:36:101 Mixer Name:Port Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:56:36:113 line:SPEAKER target port
```

On Firefox

```
2014-08-01 13:13:59:974 There are 5 mixer info objects
2014-08-01 13:13:59:974 Mixer Name:Default Audio Device
2014-08-01 13:13:59:975 line:interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
2014-08-01 13:13:59:975 Mixer Name:Built-in Input
2014-08-01 13:13:59:978 line:interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
2014-08-01 13:13:59:978 Mixer Name:Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:13:59:979 Mixer Name:Port Built-in Input
2014-08-01 13:13:59:980 Mixer Name:Port Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:13:59:981 line:SPEAKER target port
```

Anyone has any idea as to why system level details are different in Safari?

Comment: Are they both running the same version of Java?

Answer (score 0):

Some digging shows that the mixers in a java come from `MixerProviders` that the java implementation provides. It is possible that the browsers change the providers so that they may control the flow of audio within the browser.

In other words, the "system level details" aren't that of the computer, they are that of the Java *Virtual Machine*. The VM may define Mixers any way it likes. The implementation may allow for the configuration of mixers to be changed, which explains why you are getting different devices on different browsers.